# Cannot include custom font into emails

Tags: html, html-email, email-client, responsive-emails

First of all I'm sending email to number of customers that maybe gonna be like 16,000 mails and unfortunately I found issue in my custom font. I can't load it into my mail page. I tried this:

1. With link tag in HTML

   ```
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid%20Arabic%20Kufi' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   ```
2. With `@font-face` in css:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: 400;
       src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.eot);
       src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
            url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
            url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
            url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
   }
   ```
3. With `@import`

   ```
   @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css);
   ```

Don't tell me make it images because I can't and the reason is the mail form gonna be generated via PHP.

Any help will be appreciated thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Custom fonts are [not well supported in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/). It's currently not possible to display webfonts in Outlook, Gmail app, or any webmail client. However you can specify a webfont for clients that *do* support it, and system fallback fonts for those that don't.

Placing something like this inside your `<head>` will get you the best possible coverage:

```
<!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. -->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

More on [webfont support in email on Style Campaign](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/).

Comment: but how sometimes am getting mails with custom fonts and not images :S :S

Comment: What email client are you seeing custom fonts in?

Comment: hotmail.com , gmail.com :S

Comment: If you have the webfont installed locally, it will display in Hotmail and Gmail. But neither of those clients will display an externally referenced font file. Is is possible you're seeing a fallback font in the email's font stack?

Comment: hmmmm :S :S ok thanks allot for ur support i rly appreciate that :) have a good day